# Proxy failing because system resolves it using local DNS instead of VPN (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn, systemd-resolved, openconnect

I am using an VPN over openconnect through NetworkManager. I also have a proxy server whose configuration is reachable via VPN (at `http://wpad/wpad.dat`). Sporadically, when I connect to VPN it fails to use the proxy server. I think this is because DNS lookup for the proxy server is failing.

The output of `resolvectl status` shows both links used for DNS, and the vpn is the default:

```
Link 5 (vpn0)
      Current Scopes: DNS    
DefaultRoute setting: yes    
       LLMNR setting: yes    
MulticastDNS setting: no    
  DNSOverTLS setting: no    
      DNSSEC setting: no    
    DNSSEC supported: no    
  Current DNS Server: <vpn_dns_a>
         DNS Servers: <vpn_dns_a>    
                      <vpn_dns_b>    
          DNS Domain: ~.    
                      <vpn_dom>

Link 3 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: DNS    
DefaultRoute setting: yes    
       LLMNR setting: yes    
MulticastDNS setting: no    
  DNSOverTLS setting: no    
      DNSSEC setting: no    
    DNSSEC supported: no    
  Current DNS Server: <local_dns_a>
         DNS Servers: <local_dns_a>
                      <local_dns_b>
          DNS Domain: <local_dom>
```

I've verified that `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. The file itself looks like:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search <local_dom> <vpn_dom>
```

`systemd-resolve wpad` returns the server IP, but `nslookup wpad` times out. I looked at the `systemd-resolved` logs in both cases, and it looks like the former uses the VPN's DNS, but the latter (as well as curl, etc.) uses the local link's DNS. This might explain why it fails to resolve the server.

After enough fiddling (restarting network manager, clearing caches, etc.) this issue eventually works itself out, but it comes back up later. Do I need to configure anything else to make the system always use the VPN?

Comment: Try to swap the order of search <local_dom> <vpn_dom> to search <vpn_dom><local_dom>  in your resolv.conf.

Comment: That fixes it! It seems like the ordering is not updated deterministically after (sometimes the VPN domain is first, other times the local domain is first). Is this intentional?

Comment: It is just the matter of processing the resolv.conf file.

Comment: It is just the matter of processing the resolv.conf file. Actually when the vpn domain is not connected - then you might have the timeout on response. The search deremines which domain is looked up first. In a default state in most distros, the local domain is looked up first.

Comment: The resolv.conf file is managed by systemd-resolved, so it get rewritten with an inconsistent order on reboot/reconnect. If the local domain is first, DNS lookups time out and don't seem to fall back on the VPN domain. Is there a way to keep the order consistent? I was able to tweak the `vpnc-script`, which works for openconnect through CLI, but not openconnect through NetworkManager.

Answer (score 2):

Try to swap the order of `search <local_dom> <vpn_dom>` to `search <vpn_dom> <local_dom>` in your `resolv.conf` file.